# Spring Data: finding by entity or finding by entity id?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any difference between `findByEntity(Entity entity)`
and `findByEntityId(Integer id)` ?

Which one is commonly used?

Comment: Take a look at documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.
Do you see there any example with findByEntity(Entity entity)?

Comment: @Lemmy to your question: I think: In 4.4.2, Example 12 there is `List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname)`. (Ignoring the lastname-part) I think this could be interpreted as `findByEntity(Entity entity)`.

To the root question: One possible problem with `findByEntityId(Integer id)`: What should be done if the repository-type owns a property called `entityId` and another property `entity` that references a type that in turn owns a property `id`: Which one is requested? (see 4.4.3 in the docs)